# Ruby on Rails submit not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, simple-form

My problem is that the submit button on my form doesn't cause any effect.
user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: "users/sessions",
  registrations: "users/registrations"
}
```

views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:page, 'home') %>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <%= simple_form_for(@user, url: registration_path(@user)) do |f| %>
              <!-- <%= f.error_notification %> -->

              <div class="form-inputs">
                <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
                <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
                <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-actions">
                <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>

            <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controller that generated by the devise gem: `raisl g devise:controller users`

Comment: With your given routes information, you should not have any `registration_path`, but you should have a `user_registration_path` helper method. can you try using that instead? Also, if it does not work, can you post your server log when you click on the Sign Up button?

Comment: For your routes.rb file can you just use: `devise_for :users` ?

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam i changed registration_path to user_registration_path in the view file, but it didn't work.And nothing added when i click on the Sign Up button.

Comment: @DustinFisher That would casuse a routing error.

Comment: Are you doing something outside of the normal devise functionality that requires you to setup your routes that way?

Comment: @DustinFisher No, i was not do that.